# IntelliJ IDEA Hibernate Code Generation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm trying to generate Java classes from a MySQL Database using IntelliJ IDEA. The problem is that by default the generation doesn't detect many to many tables, but instead maps the tables to classes directly, adding classes for many to many tables.

Example: I have tables "User" and "Conversation" and a relationship many-to-many between them. Now I would expect the code to consist of two classes, each one having one collection of the other, but what I also get is the ManyToMany class consisting the FKs from each one, and I don't want that.

The equivalence of that is Eclipse's Detect many-to-many tables.
[image: Hibernate Code Generation Configurations within Eclipse IDE]

If anyone has had a similar issue I'd be greatly thankful to hear from you.

Regards

Comment: I think a class for many to many is correct.  You need a separate class to break the circular nature of that relationship.

Comment: I agree that there should be a table between those two, but a  class shouldn't be necessary if mapped right, and Eclipse does just that.